# npm ci command fails in GitHub actions when running on Node 16

Tags: github-actions, npm-ci

I'm running `npm ci` on Node 16 in GitHub workflow actions and keep getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-01-10T11_38_28_617Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I tried deleting the package-lock.json file and running `npm i` locally and uploading the new file. But it did not make a difference.

**Workflow file**

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "*" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "*" ]

jobs:
  test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - name: Build the Docker image and run tests
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm test
```

Please advise how I can resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like some of the packages in your `package-lock.json` file are in private registries.

You need to login to that registry as it is saying in the error. Otherwise NPM cannot pull those packages.

Comment: but how come the workflow on node 14 and node 12 pass?

Comment: Post the workflow file and we can see. There shouldn’t be any reason why it would work on 12 and 14 but not 16

Comment: Added the workflow

Comment: have you checked the directory it tries to run `npm ci`? Since you can't run the command outside the directory which has `package-lock.json`